# Return 404 when using the ProducesAttribute for image/jpg in ASP.Net Core Web APi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I hae the following endpoint supposed to return image. I want to return a code 404 when there is no image for the given employee id

```
        [HttpGet("{employeeId}/images/picture")]        
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [Produces("image/jpg")]
        public ActionResult GetImage(int employeeId)
        {
            var fileName = _employeeService.GetImage(employeeId);

            if (fileName == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return PhysicalFile(fileName, "image/jpg", $"{employeeId}-picture.jpg");
        }
```

The problem I am having is that this return a HTTP 406 (Not Acceptable) if the file cannot exist.
When debugging, I can see it go into the `return NotFound()` line.

It works as expected if I take out the `[Produces("image/jpg")]` attribute. My guess is that filter is not happy with a 404 being returned for `Content-Type=image/jpg`

I giess I could leave it out but I would really like to understand what's happening and see if there is a solution.

Thanks

Comment: It might be the order you're having your filters in. Try moving the ```[Produces("image/jpg")]``` beneath ```[HttpGet("{employeeId}/images/picture")]``` also swap the ProducesResponseType's. So the order would be like 1. HttpGet 2. Produces 3. reponse 200 4. response 404

Comment: @scircia, thanks for that but it didn't make a difference. Still getting a 406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Produces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#List_of_common_media_types) attribute is used to specify the data type returned by the operation.

Because you limit the current method to return only the data type of `image/jpg`, NotFound() will not be allowed to receive, so `406 Not Acceptable` message will appear.

To return 404 information normally, add an allowed type `application/json` to the Produces attribute like this:

```
[Produces("image/jpg", "application/json")]
```